# How could I interpret these-2 YUV modulated picture given in wikipedia? is it correct simulation? or something I'm missing?

Tags: demodulation, tv, colour

While reading the wikipedia article on [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) color modulation (which is used in [PAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) color tv receivers); I visited this diagram:

[image: Wikipedia screenshot] ([Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Barn-yuv.png));

(and according to the image description there; i.e.

> "An image along with its Y′, U, and V components respectively";

the 3rd one is U-component and 4th one is the V-component of the 1st image. Well.

---

But there;  the component U has been described as

U = approx  0.492 (B - Y')   ... (where Y is Luma).

So, if the 3rd image show only U; i.e. 0.492 (B - Y') or 0.492 X (Blue-(0.299R+ 0.587G + 0.114B)) ; then in the ultimate result;  there would be equal visual reduction in R and G; and B would be the most prominent.

(As well; they've [provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV444_to_RGB888_conversion) a formula too;
U= -0.147R -0.289G +0.436B ; that shows a positive value for only blue, and a negative values of both R and G)

If someone try to simulate it as visible picture; the picture would contain only-blue (which is non-negative).

But surprisingly, in image 3, there is high portion of green too ; i.e. green is  behaving in similar, positive way) ; though there I could not find any trace of red component with ms-paint Eyedropper tool.

[image: labelled as U but doubt]

(My eyedropper samples on downloaded [original-file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Barn-yuv.png) ranges from R=0, G=83, B=172 to R=0, G=191, B= 64; and in all samples R=0; on Paint's 255 scale)

So; **my question is; is it a wrong picture of U component?**

Even if I consider they made a negative copy of U (i.e. gave a -U); still we would obtain Red and Green together as positive; and blue as negative.

U= -0.147R -0.289G +0.436B

= > -U = +0.147R +0.289G -0.436B

But the image shows G and B; not R and G.

---

In the same way; the 4 th image (V or approx. 0.877(R-Y')) also seems to me showing anomaly from the definitions.

[Given equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV444_to_RGB888_conversion);

V= +0.615R -0.515G -0.100B

So the positive image would only Red color. But similar to 3rd image; it show proportions of Red and Green; not Red-only.

[image: Labelled as V but doubted]

(ms-paint eyedropper samples from original image shown R=147, G=81, B=0 to R=102, G=153, B=0; and in all sampled dots B=0)

If it was a negative copy of V-component; Then we should get positive values of G and B. Not R and G.

---

So; if these 2 images are correct examples of U and V; what thing I missing about the concept of U and V? what is the basis behind that "extra green" in both the image 3 and 4?

---

**in simple words;**

*If from a blue image (Component B) if I snatch away a colorless component (Y') then how I get a blue-green picture and not an only-blue picture? or why not blue red?*

*And same way, if I snatch away a colorless component (Y') from a Red image (Component R); then how I can obtain a Red-Green image and not a only-Red image? or why not blue-red?*

Comment: The U and V images should have been displayed in monochrome, just as the Y image was. If a coloured image is a 'vector' containing R, G and B components, then Y, U and V are scalars, they do not have and are not representable as coloured images.

Comment: @user:16880 (David) inviting you to visit this question.